# Second Route doesn't work in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I originally thought that this was an issue with my routes as one route works and the other doesn't. However, upon changing my route around it is now the otherway round. The route code is below:

```
_website_site:
    resource: "@SiteWebsiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /   

_mobile_site:
    resource: "@SiteMobileBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /m
```

This code is situated at the bottom of my route_dev.yml in my app folder. Using the code this way the /m/ prefix works but if i reverse them then the / works and not the /m/.

is it possible to have more then 1 route in the app\routing_dev.yml file? If not then how would this normally work?

Cheers

Comment: What do you get if you run `app/console router:debug`? Are the route names the same in both of the files?

Comment: No the route names are different but I can do it at the moment as I don't have my pc. If you look at the previous edit you can see more of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding

```
    prefix: m_
```

To your routes from mobile routing.yml (after the defaults thing )

Comment: i got the following error:
contains unsupported keys for "_homepage": "name_prefix". Expected one of: "resource", "type", "prefix", "pattern", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition".

Comment: Try to use `prefix` instead `name_prefix`

Comment: @Victor thx, indeed the 'name_prifix' is used for REST requests :)

Comment: i have tried this and it doesn't look like it is this causing the issue.

Comment: I've updated my question as the general prefix does work as long as the route is at the bottom the other route will not work. Comes up with No route found for "GET /" but if i swap the two around it comes up no problem. Also, yes cache has been cleared.

Comment: I hope you added the `prefix: m_` to the routes in the `Site/MobileBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` <- file

Comment: @ŢîganIon The only thing that was wrong was the fact i had stupidly left the route names the same on both bundles and it was matching the last set that had been entered